# Capturing TextChanged event inside a Listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView containing an EditText. I want to capture the textchanged event of this textbox and update other columns.

Inside my customAdapter I did this

```
public View getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistview, null);
    }

    EditText edQty = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.cartProductQuantity);
    edQty.addTextChangedListener(new QtyChangedWatcher(position, v));
}
```

The event is getting fired on its own even when the user has not changed anything. Moreover when the user changes input only for the first row, the event is getting fired, but for all textboxes in the listview.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does any of `EditText` objects have focus when your `Activity` created?

Comment: I'm not sure whether what I did was right. In my even code, I checked for before and after values and if they were different, I proceeded to my code. I stored the previous value using the setTag function in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistview, null);

    EditText edQty = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.cartProductQuantity);
    edQty.addTextChangedListener(new QtyChangedWatcher(position, v));
    }
}
```

(move your addTextChangedListener inside the if condition)